# Problema con do/while y switch/case?

Tags: javascript

Es un juego sencillo en el que por el momento solo hay 3 funciones , una para elegir el signo X o O, otra para la jugada del humano dado por un listener de click a la casilla del tateti y la otra función es la jugada de la maquina con `math.random`para que la elección se de al azar, pero no entiendo porque una jugada no habilita la otra automáticamente, intente hacerlo con `do/while` y habilitando según el turno del humano y maquina respectivamente pero no funciona. Que esta pasando?

Dejo el código a mano:

```js
const empates = 0;
const ganadosComputadora = 0;
const ganadosHumano = 0;

const casillas = document.querySelectorAll(".casilla");

let signo;
let signoComputadora;

let turno;
let basta = [];

const elegirOX = () => {
  const eleccion = prompt("Elige O o X");
  if (eleccion === "o") {
    signo = "o";
    signoComputadora = "x";
    turno = "humano";
  } else if (eleccion === "x") {
    signo = "x";
    signoComputadora = "o";
    turno = "computadora";
  } else {
    alert("Elige O o X");
    // elegirOX();
  }
};
elegirOX();

const juegaHumano = () => {
  casillas.forEach((casilla) => {
    console.log(casilla);
    casilla.addEventListener("click", () => {
      casilla.innerText = signo;
      basta.push("1");
      turno = "computadora";
    });
  });
};

const juegaComputadora = () => {
  let jugada = Math.floor(Math.random() * casillas.length);
  console.log(casillas[jugada]);
  casillas[jugada].innerText = signoComputadora;
  basta.push("1");
  turno = "humano";
};

do {
  switch (turno) {
    case "humano":
      juegaHumano();
      break;
    case "computadora":
      juegaComputadora();
      break;
    default:
      console.log("Esperando jugada");
  }
} while (basta.length == 3);

console.log(basta.length);
console.log(turno);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  background-color: lightskyblue;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 80px;
}

h2,
h3 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 80px;
  color: whitesmoke;
}

span {
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding: 30px;
  border: 2px solid lightgray;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#turno {
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: 30px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 15pt;
  font-weight: bolder;
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: 2px solid lightgray;
  /* display: none; */
}

.tateti {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#tablero {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
}

.casilla {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#jugadores {
  display: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15pt;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.marcador {
  /* display: none; */
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./src/styles.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>TA TE TI</h1>
    </header>

    <!-- <section id=ficha>
        <h3>Elige una ficha:</h3>
        <span id="x">X</span>
        <span id="o">O</span>
    </section> -->

    <section class="jugadores">
      <div id="computadora"></div>
      <div id="humano"></div>
    </section>

    <div class="tateti">
      <section id="turno"></section>

      <section id="tablero">
        <div class="casilla"></div>
        <div class="casilla"></div>
        <div class="casilla"></div>
        <div class="casilla"></div>
        <div class="casilla"></div>
        <div class="casilla"></div>
        <div class="casilla"></div>
        <div class="casilla"></div>
        <div class="casilla"></div>
      </section>
      <section class="marcador">
        <section id="ganadosHumano"></section>
        <section id="ganadosComputadora"></section>
        <section id="empates"></section>
      </section>
    </div>

    <script src="./src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que la condición de tu `do-while` dice que debe ejecutarse siempre y cuando la longitud de `basta` sea igual a 3. Cuando lo declaras, el valor de `length` es 0 (se aumenta en 1 por que sea realiza una jugada), pero de igual forma nunca llega a ser 3, por lo tanto solo se ejecutaría 1 vez.

Por otro lado, no te recomiendo llamar `addEventListener` (tu función `juegaHumano`) dentro de un loop o bucle, porque estarías agregando muchos eventos a las casillas y solo necesitas hacerlo 1 vez.

Por último, el problema de utilizar bucles y esperar por un evento del usuario, es que los bucles se ejecutan de forma `síncrona`, en pocas palabras, tu programa se congelará. Como los eventos creados por `addEventListener` son asíncronos (ya que esperan por la interacción del usuario) podrías hacer algo como esto:

```js
const empates = 0;
const ganadosComputadora = 0;
const ganadosHumano = 0;

const casillas = document.querySelectorAll(".casilla");

let signo;
let signoComputadora;

let turno;
let basta = [];

const juegaComputadora = () => {
  let jugada = Math.floor(Math.random() * casillas.length);
  console.log(casillas[jugada]);
  casillas[jugada].innerText = signoComputadora;
  basta.push("1");
  turno = "humano";
};

const juegaHumano = () => {
  casillas.forEach((casilla) => {
    console.log(casilla);
    casilla.addEventListener("click", () => {
      casilla.innerText = signo;
      basta.push("1");
      turno = "computadora";
      juegaComputadora(); // Ejecutamos el turno de la computadora al terminar el turno del usuario
    });
  });
};

// Inicializamos los eventos en las casillas y esperamos que el usuario ejecute el evento
juegaHumano();

const elegirOX = () => {
  const eleccion = prompt("Elige O o X");
  if (eleccion === "o") {
    signo = "o";
    signoComputadora = "x";
    turno = "humano";
  } else if (eleccion === "x") {
    signo = "x";
    signoComputadora = "o";
    turno = "computadora";
    juegaComputadora(); // Ejecutamos el turno de la computadora
  } else {
    alert("Elige O o X");
    // elegirOX();
  }
};
elegirOX();

// Evitamos usar el do-while para que no se congele.
//do {
//  switch (turno) {
//    case "humano":
//      juegaHumano();
//      break;
//    case "computadora":
//      juegaComputadora();
//      break;
//    default:
//      console.log("Esperando jugada");
//  }
//} while (basta.length == 3);
//console.log(basta.length);
//console.log(turno);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  background-color: lightskyblue;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 80px;
}

h2,
h3 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 80px;
  color: whitesmoke;
}

span {
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding: 30px;
  border: 2px solid lightgray;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#turno {
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: 30px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 15pt;
  font-weight: bolder;
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: 2px solid lightgray;
  /* display: none; */
}

.tateti {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#tablero {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
}

.casilla {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#jugadores {
  display: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15pt;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.marcador {
  /* display: none; */
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./src/styles.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>TA TE TI</h1>
    </header>

    <!-- <section id=ficha>
        <h3>Elige una ficha:</h3>
        <span id="x">X</span>
        <span id="o">O</span>
    </section> -->

    <section class="jugadores">
      <div id="computadora"></div>
      <div id="humano"></div>
    </section>

    <div class="tateti">
      <section id="turno"></section>

      <section id="tablero">
        <div class="casilla"></div>
        <div class="casilla"></div>
        <div class="casilla"></div>
        <div class="casilla"></div>
        <div class="casilla"></div>
        <div class="casilla"></div>
        <div class="casilla"></div>
        <div class="casilla"></div>
        <div class="casilla"></div>
      </section>
      <section class="marcador">
        <section id="ganadosHumano"></section>
        <section id="ganadosComputadora"></section>
        <section id="empates"></section>
      </section>
    </div>

    <script src="./src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Lo último que te quedaría por hacer, es que tu función `juegaComputadora` evalúe si la casilla elegida al azar no esté llena, sino, que elija otra.

Comment: Excelente!! Ahora entiendo, te agradezco muchisimo por tu ayudaa ! @C. Rodriguez